# Swift 2 issue with a closure for groupBy collection

Tags: group-by, swift2, closures

The code below is written in order to group journal publications by year of publication.

But I got the error "Cannot convert value of type '(Journal) -> Int' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'"

Here's the playground with a stripped down version of the real code for you to play around http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/1de81132cb2430962b248d2d6ff64922e2fe912b1480db6a7276c6a03047dd89

```
class Journal {

    var releaseDate: Int = 0

    static var journals = [Journal]()

    class func groupedReduce<S: SequenceType, K: Hashable, U> (
        source: S, 
        initial: U,
        combine: (U, S.Generator.Element) -> U,
        groupBy: (S.Generator.Element) -> K
    )
        -> [K:U]
    {
        var result: [K:U] = [:]

        for element in source {
            let key = groupBy(element)
            result[key] = combine(result[key] ?? initial, element)
        }

        return result
    }



    class func groupBy() {

        let byYear = { (journal: Journal) in
            journal.releaseDate
        }

        let groupedJournals = groupedReduce(journals, initial: 0, combine:+, groupBy: byYear)

        print("Grouped journals = \(groupedJournals)")
    }
}



Journal.journals = [Journal(), Journal(), Journal(), Journal()]

for j in Journal.journals {
    j.releaseDate = 1
}


Journal.groupBy()
```

Comment: there are more than simple trouble with you code. the first one is that compiler is not able to infer type of groupedJournals. using let gropedJournals: Int = .... should solve it. The worst is that Journal has no member Generator ..... just continue step by step

Comment: other trouble is that operator + expects both operands and result to be the same type ...

Comment: You mix things up. S is a SequenceType, @user3441734

Comment: my bad, let gropedJournals: [Int:Int]

Comment: look here ... combine(result[key] ?? initial, element) if you would like to apply + operator, initial (in you case Int) must be the same type as element (in your case Journal) but this is impossible. i suggest you to forget generics and try to implement your functionality with concrete types first.

Comment: please, update your question with some explanation, what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated. Below is a `groupBy` function that group elements of an array according to criteria of your choice. [Playground](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/d11691e6085178ae0acbd574c665448a32d4586330d8d350a4ed7edd887d007f)

```
import Foundation

class Journal {
    var releaseDate: Int = 0

    init(_ releaseDate: Int) {
        self.releaseDate = releaseDate
    }
}

extension Array {
    func groupBy<T: Hashable>(f: Element -> T) -> [T: [Element]] {
        var results = [T: [Element]]()

        for element in self {
            let key = f(element)
            if results[key] == nil {
                results[key] = [Element]()
            }
            results[key]!.append(element)
        }

        return results
    }

    func groupBy2<T: Hashable>(f: Element -> T) -> [T: [Element]] {
        return self.reduce([T: [Element]]()) { (var aggregate, element) in
            let key = f(element)
            if aggregate[key] == nil {
                aggregate[key] = [Element]()
            }

            aggregate[key]!.append(element)
            return aggregate
        }
    }
}


let journals = [Journal(2015), Journal(2016), Journal(2015), Journal(2014)]
let groupedJournals = journals.groupBy {
    $0.releaseDate
}

print(groupedJournals)
```

Comment: Thanks @Code Different but I already have a mere groupBy for long. What I am trying to achieve is an evolved reduce() version of the groupBy.

Comment: I really wanted to get the answer of my question. How can I fix the syntax error I am talking in my question? @Code Different